# history.back not behaving as expected in Karma

Tags: javascript, web, iframe, karma-runner, browser-history

When I run a basic test case like this:

```js
  fdescribe('Browser back button', () => {

    fit('should return to previous', async () => {

      const originalHref = window.location.href;
      window.history.pushState({}, 'Test', '/test');
      window.history.back();  // This doesn't seem to be working.
      expect(window.location.href).toEqual(originalHref);
    });
```

I get a failure with the message "Expected 'http://localhost:9876/test' to equal 'http://localhost:9876/context.html'." So clearly the pushState() worked but the back() did not.

Karma runs tests in an inner iframe. When I paste the first three lines in order into the browser's JavaScript console, the navigation works as expected. So there must be something different between the behavior of the window and the behavior of the inner iframe in this case.

This is Karma 5.1 on Chrome.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back) API is asynchronous

> This method is asynchronous. Add a listener for the `popstate` event in order to determine when the navigation has completed.

So the navigation back is triggered but the test does not wait for it to complete and the check fails.

We need to convert the test into an asynchronous one by adding `done` param (it's one method I know, maybe there are other ways too). And use `popstate` event handler to wait for navigation and complete the test.

```
fdescribe('Browser back button', () => {
  fit('should return to previous', (done) => {
    const originalHref = window.location.href;
    window.history.pushState({}, 'Test', '/test');

    window.history.back(); // gets executed asynchonously
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
      // history.back() is done now
      expect(window.location.href).toEqual(originalHref);
      done();
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, I was many hours into this problem and was about to resort to testing my change with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Vitalii's answer is the most generally applicable one since it relies only on browser built-ins. Here is a basic suite for Angular users, based on their code.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fdescribe('Browser back button', () => {

    let location: Location;
    let currentUrl: string;
    const previousUrl = '/test';

    beforeEach(() => {
      location = TestBed.inject(Location);
      currentUrl = location.normalize(window.location.href);
      location.go(previousUrl);
      location.go(currentUrl);
    });

    afterEach(() => location.go(currentUrl));

    fit('should return to previous', done => {
      location.subscribe(e => {
        expect(e.url).toEqual(previousUrl);
        done();
      });
      location.back();
    });
  });
});
```

To customize the back button's behavior, rename 'should return to previous' to describe whatever you want the button to do instead, and update the test accordingly.